# Pymedia installation on Windows with Python 2.6

Tags: python

I am trying to install latest version of  Pymedia from sources. I have Python2.6 and there is no binary available.

Started with:

```
python setup.py build
```

and got the following messages:

```
Using WINDOWS configuration...
Path for  OGG not found.
Path for  VORBIS not found.
Path for  FAAD not found.
Path for  MP3LAME not found.
Path for  VORBISENC not found.
Path for  ALSA not found.
Continue building pymedia ? [Y,n]:Y
```

After putting the source code for OGG and VORBIS in a directory where I had put the pymedia source code, it was able to find those libs  But when I put the source code libmp3lame-3.95 in that dir, it couldn't find it.

After reading setup.py file of pymedia , I also tried putting a dll for this library under libmp3lame/Release but it was still unable to locate it.

Can someone help? Is there a binary distribution available for Pymedia using Python 2.6 or higher?

Answer (score 8):

Somebody has done it, if you're just after pymedia for python2.6 on windows:

Have a look here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

There's also a version for python2.7

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I spent about one hour to find the way to install PyMedia for python 2.6 from binaries on windows. One minute after I found your answer the PyMedia was installed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install all of those modules separately, in a similar fashion (`python setup.py install`).

Those other modules are just prerequisites to pymedia, and need to be installed prior to installing pymedia.
It's kind of a pain with some libraries, and [there are alternatives](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to take care of installing everything for you.

Comment: easy_install is a god send. there is also "pip", which supports installing projects that need to be checked out from a repo. (link: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)