# Issue with installing PyMedia for in Python 3.3

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, syntax-error, windows-7-x64

So I've been trying to install PyMedia for a bit now, and I've gone through many troubleshooting steps to get here.  Where I'm at right now, I've gotten the binary for MinGW installed, and updated.  Then when I try and run the setup file, there a few errors, but I can continue past them, however, after those errors, I get a long string pointer issues within the program acodec.c

```
C:\Python33\Lib\pymedia-1.3.7.3>python setup.py build_ext --compiler=mingw32
Using WINDOWS configuration...

('Path for ', 'OGG', 'not found.')
('Path for ', 'VORBIS', 'not found.')
('Path for ', 'FAAD', 'not found.')
('Path for ', 'MP3LAME', 'not found.')
('Path for ', 'VORBISENC', 'not found.')
('Path for ', 'ALSA', 'not found.')
Continue building pymedia ? [Y,n]:
running build_ext
building 'pymedia.audio.acodec' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\audio
creating build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\audio\acodec
creating build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\audio\libavcodec
creating build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\audio\libavcodec\liba52
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -DBUILD_NUM=1878 -DWIN32 -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H -DUDF_CACHE=1 -IC:\Python33\Lib\pymedia-1.3.7.3 -Iaudio/ -IC:\Python33\include -IC:\Python33\include -c audio\acodec/acodec.c -o build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\audio\acodec\acodec.o
audio\acodec/acodec.c:217: error: 'getreadbufferproc' undeclared here (not in a function)
audio\acodec/acodec.c:217: error: expected '}' before 'acstring_buffer_getbuf'
audio\acodec/acodec.c: In function 'acstring_str':
audio\acodec/acodec.c:227: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_FromStringAndSize'
audio\acodec/acodec.c:227: warning: return makes pointer from integer without acast
audio\acodec/acodec.c: At top level:
audio\acodec/acodec.c:233: warning: missing braces around initializer
audio\acodec/acodec.c:233: warning: (near initialization for 'ACStringType.ob_base.ob_base')
audio\acodec/acodec.c:235: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:238: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:245: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:249: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:250: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:252: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:253: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:254: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:272: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c: In function 'SetStructVal':
audio\acodec/acodec.c:279: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyInt_Check'
audio\acodec/acodec.c:282: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyInt_AsLong'
audio\acodec/acodec.c: In function 'SetExtraData':
audio\acodec/acodec.c:291: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_Check'
audio\acodec/acodec.c:294: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_Size'
audio\acodec/acodec.c:298: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_AsString'
audio\acodec/acodec.c:298: warning: passing argument 2 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c: In function 'SetAttribute':
audio\acodec/acodec.c:305: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyInt_FromLong'
audio\acodec/acodec.c:305: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c: In function 'Codec_GetID':
audio\acodec/acodec.c:362: warning: return makes pointer from integer without acast
audio\acodec/acodec.c: At top level:
audio\acodec/acodec.c:405: warning: missing braces around initializer
audio\acodec/acodec.c:405: warning: (near initialization for 'FrameType.ob_base.ob_base')
audio\acodec/acodec.c:407: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:410: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:422: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:425: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:426: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:434: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:435: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:442: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:444: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c: In function 'ACodec_Encode':
audio\acodec/acodec.c:668: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'avcodec_encode_audio' differ in signedness
audio\acodec/acodec.c:677: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c: At top level:
audio\acodec/acodec.c:823: warning: missing braces around initializer
audio\acodec/acodec.c:823: warning: (near initialization for 'DecoderType.ob_base.ob_base')
audio\acodec/acodec.c:825: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:828: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:840: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:843: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:844: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:851: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:860: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:861: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:862: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:887: warning: missing braces around initializer
audio\acodec/acodec.c:887: warning: (near initialization for 'EncoderType.ob_base.ob_base')
audio\acodec/acodec.c:889: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:892: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:904: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:907: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
audio\acodec/acodec.c:908: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:915: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:924: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:925: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:926: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
audio\acodec/acodec.c:944: warning: return type defaults to 'int'
audio\acodec/acodec.c: In function 'DL_EXPORT':
audio\acodec/acodec.c:944: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'initacodec'
audio\acodec/acodec.c:1005: error: expected '{' at end of input
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

C:\Python33\Lib\pymedia-1.3.7.3>
```

Any idea what I can do to fix this?  Just to clarify, I have very little experience with C, C++, and Python.  So if you explanation could be simplified at all, I would very much appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: A simple google search of the errors of the missing paths gave me this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141701/pymedia-installation-on-windows-with-python-2-6

Comment: Well, that would be more helpful if they were talking about 3.x, but they're installing for 2.7.  I looked into the binaries, and they were only for 2.6 and 2.7, there wasn't any 3.x support there.  Maybe I've missed something, but I didn't see that helping with my 3.x problem.  Other then, install 2.7 which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Uh they aren't ready for 3.x then; python 3 made some big changes that could result in problems with many libraries, just use python 2 and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am heading down the pygame.cdrom route as I this my first alternative.